# Matlab bug with root and conj

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, complex-numbers

I think I found a Matlab bug (I am using R2023a currently). My question is, how can I circumvent it.

Consider the following code

```matlab
syms z
r1 = vpa( root( z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z^1 + 1 == 0, z, 1 ) )          % 0.5 + 0.866025403784438646763723170753i
r2 = conj( vpa( root( z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z^1 + 1 == 0, z, 1 ) ) )  % 0.5 - 0.866025403784438646763723170753i

s1 = vpa( root( z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z^1 + 1 == 0, z, 1 ) )          % 0.5 + 0.866025403784438646763723170753i
s2 = vpa( conj( root( z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z^1 + 1 == 0, z, 1 ) ) )  % 0.5 + 0.866025403784438646763723170753i
```

where `r1` and `r2` are correctly conjugated to each other, but `s1` and `s2` are the same. Thus, matlab seems to ignore the `conj` call for a "`root`-object" (I do not know the correct terminology here.

- How can I correctly conjugate a "`root`-object"?
- Respectively (my actual question may be easier to solve): How can I identify in Matlab whether two values are conjugate to each other.

Comment: I agree it's a bug. It probably results from the naive application of the complex conjugate root theorem. While the roots of the polynomial (with real coefficients) and their conjugates are the same *set*, they are not the same *vector*, since conjugation changes their order. And order is certainly relevant for `root` objects as your example clearly shows.

Comment: You can tell if `a` and `b` are conjugates of each other if `abs(a).^2 == a.*b`, for example. —— `vpa` in your case is solving the root problem numerically. You can also call `solve` instead, which will solve it symbolically.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no published preferred "order" (that I can find, anyway) for which root is root(expression,1), the Symbolic Toolbox is free to give you any order it wants.  And since the Symbolic Toolbox knows that roots come in complex conjugate pairs when the coefficients are real, in the case of conj(roots(expression,1)), apparently the toolbox implicitly just switched the background order on you to simplify the expression. This expression is apparently interpreted as "conjugate of one of the roots of the expression", not "conjugate of the first root of this expression given a preferred order". Is the fact that the "order" of the roots is arbitrary and can be changed in the background depending on calling sequence and toolbox simplifications a bug? Particularly given that there is no preferred "order" published in the doc? I leave that up to you. If you request all of them at once and then convert them maybe you can work with that in your code without ambiguity. E.g.,

```
>> syms z
>> ex = z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z^1 + 1 == 0;
>> s = root(ex)
s =
 root(z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1, z, 1)
 root(z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1, z, 2)
 root(z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1, z, 3)
 root(z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1, z, 4)
 root(z^5 + z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1, z, 5)
>> vpa(s)
ans =
 - 0.5 - 0.86602540378443864676372317075294i
   0.5 - 0.86602540378443864676372317075294i
   0.5 + 0.86602540378443864676372317075294i
 - 0.5 + 0.86602540378443864676372317075294i
                                        -1.0
```

It would have been nice if MATLAB had returned root(ex,4) for conj(root(ex,1)) for consistency though. Maybe I will post a Question on MATLAB Answers to get their thoughts on this. Even nicer still if they had returned the complex conjugate pairs next to each other.